# Can I infer causality group of correlated random variables?

Tags: correlation, causality

I have a group of random variables (vectors of numbers) that are highly correlated $(corr>0.9)$.
I wonder if I can infer which of these variables is the dominant one: the one that causes the other variables to behave similarly.

My first thought is to measure the average correlation of each variable to the other variables.
And the variable with the largest average correlation will be assumed to cause the other variables.

Does that make sense? Is there another way to find out causality in this case?

Comment: The book Causality: Models, Reasoning, and Inference, by Judea Pearl, goes into that, but as it's a very advanced book, and I'm going through it rather slowly, I'm afraid I can't help you much. There are, though, ways of determining, given a particular causal model, whether your data is consistent with that model. There are even ways of learning the causal model from the data, but those are super-advanced.

Comment: @AdrianKeister Thanks for your comment. I will look up existing implementations of these advanced approaches. Maybe I'll be able to use them without really understanding them. But what I was really wondering is if my intuition above is correct?

Comment: I doubt that your intuition would work in this case. You could probably come up with a decent counterexample to that procedure.